# How Do I Add A Borderless Entry To A Page From A Class Library In .Net MAUI

Tags: maui

I am able to set up and add a Borderless Entry to a page
i) from XAML,
and ii) from code behind.
However I would like to create the page UI from a method in a referenced class library.  I am able to create a standard Entry but I am at a loss on how to create a Borderless Entry when the handler is in the project and I can't reference the project from the class library.
Any help would be appreciated.
Demo Project :  https://github.com/GDT48/BorderlessEntryInLibrary7.git

In the Project MainPage I have:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    var newEntry = new BorderlessEntry()
    {
        Placeholder = "Borderless Entry Added From Code Behind",
        PlaceholderColor = Colors.Red,
    };
    this.EntryLayout.Add(newEntry);
    Class1.AddEntryControl(EntryLayout);
}
```

This add a BorderlessEntry control to the VerticalStackLayout (EntryLayout) with code behind.
In the Solution I have a Class Library (ClassLibrary7) with a method AddEntryControl() passing the EntryLayount as a parameter. Currently the method is:

```
public static void AddEntryControl(VerticalStackLayout layout)
{
    var newEntry = new Entry()
    {
        Placeholder = "Entry Added From Class Library",
        PlaceholderColor = Colors.Red,
    };
    layout.Add(newEntry);
}
```

which successfully adds a normal Entry control but I would like to have this being:

```
var newEntry = new BorderlessEntry()
```

but I don't know how to create a BorderlessEntry control in a Class Library. In the project,
A new class is added inheriting from Entry,
Resources are added to the Windows App.xml - which does not exist in the Class Libray,
Changes are appended to the EntryHandler in App.xml.cs - again does not exist in the Class Library.

I am guessing I need to reference the BorderlessEntry class in the Project (BorderlessEntryInLibrary7) but I don't know how to do this from a Class Library.

Comment: you register the handler in your in `CreateMauiApp` like you normally would, you just reference the class that exists in the library project

Comment: You have `public class BorderlessEntry : Entry { }` declared in your app and you have `public static class Class1 { }` declared in your class library. It is not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I see what you are trying to do. No. The project is the whole machine. The class library is a part from the machine. So you make one class lib to have the borderless entry code. And you reference this lib, in your other library. All kinds of design abominations (referencing the project, adding common files as links, etc...) are the wrong way to structure your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a borderless Entry in the Library method and then add the BorderlessEntry by calling the method in the Maui project, you can refer to the following steps：

Step 1. Add custom Entry contorl class inherited `Entry` in Library, and define the method to create BorderlessEntry in the class.

```
public class BorderlessEntry : Entry
{
    public BorderlessEntry()
    {
    }
    public static void AddEntryControl(VerticalStackLayout layout)
    {    
        var borderlessEntry = new BorderlessEntry()
        {
            Placeholder = "Entry Added From Class Library",
            PlaceholderColor = Colors.Red,
        };
        layout.Add(borderlessEntry);
    }
}
```

Step 2. Create a new handler class in the library and define the borderless style of the Entry in the class:

```
public class BorderlessEntryHandler : EntryHandler
{
    public BorderlessEntryHandler()
    {
        Mapper.AppendToMapping("Borderless",(handler,view)=>
        {
            if(view is BorderlessEntry)
            {
#if ANDROID
                handler.PlatformView.Background = null;
                handler.Platform.SetBackgroundColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Transparent)
                handler.PlatformView.SetPadding(15, 15, 15, 15);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Step 3. Create a static class with an MauiAppBuilder extension method in your library project.

```
public static class Config
{
    public static MauiAppBuilder UseMyPlugin(this MauiAppBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureMauiHandlers(handlers =>
        {
            handlers.AddHandler(typeof(BorderlessEntry),typeof(BorderlessEntryHandler));
        });
        return builder;
    }
}
```

Step 4. Add `.UseMyPlugin()` to the MAUI project's `MauiProgram.cs` file

```
    public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
    {
        var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
        builder
            .UseMauiApp<App>()
            .UseMyPlugin()
            .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
            {
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
            });

#if DEBUG
        builder.Logging.AddDebug();
#endif

        return builder.Build();
    }
```

Step 5. Use `AddEntryControl` method in the behind code file of Maui project like the code you provided.

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BorderlessEntry.AddEntryControl(EntryLayout);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but this does not answer my question.

Comment: Thanks for reply but this does not answer my question. 
I would like to be able to create a BorderlessEntry in the library and then to use this control in a method in the library to create a new BorderlessEntry and add this to the layout in the project UI.
I tried steps 1 and 2 but this did not work.

Comment: @GDT48 According to your demand, I have re-edited the content of step 1 and step 5 in the answer.  If you still encounter some problems in the future, you can continue to express the problem.

Comment: Many thanks now works for me.
Needed to change to 'public class BorderlessEntry : Entry' in step 1 - Static class 'BorderlessEntry' cannot derive from type 'Entry'. Static classes must derive from object.
Also fully qualify in step 5 - ClassLibrary7.Handlers.BorderlessEntry.AddEntryControl(EntryLayout);